# Searching for a string and print a line from file

Tags: java, search, printing, line

I am trying to be able to make a method in my program which will enable me to search for a string and then print the entire line which this string is located in inside a textfile. Any pointers? I have tried to do this, but I keep getting nothing out -.-

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class Oblig2 {

public static void main (String[] args) {
final Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int menyvalg=0;
Meny menyen = new Meny();

menyen.meny(); 
}
}   
 //Selve menyen til programmet i en egen klasse.

 class Meny {
PrintWriter fil;
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);    

public void meny() {
try{
    fil=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fugler.txt", true));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Filen finnes ikke");
} 


int menyvalg=0;
int menykall=1; 
//Menyen vil her bli repetert helt til en taster inn 4 og endrer menykall til 0.
do{
    //Selve menyen vil bli repetert helt til brukeren velger en av menyens alternativer.
    do{
    System.out.println("====== Meny for registrering av fugleobservasjoner =====");

    System.out.println("\n1. Registrer en fugleobservasjon");
    System.out.println("2. Skriv ut alle fugleobservasjoner av en type");
    System.out.println("3. Skriv ut alle fugleobservasjoner på ett bestemt sted");
    System.out.println("4. Avslutt systemet");

    System.out.println("\nVennligst velg en aksjon: ");
    menyvalg = input.nextInt();

        } while(menyvalg < 1 || menyvalg > 4);

    switch (menyvalg){
    case 1: registrering();
    break;
    case 2: //fugleType();
    break; 
    case 3:
    break;
    case 4:menykall=0;
        }
    }while(menykall>=1); 
  }

void registrering () {

System.out.println("Velkommen til registreringen av fugleobservasjoner.");
System.out.println("Begynner registreringen (Lagrer seg i filen fugler.txt): ");

    try { 
    fil = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fugler.txt", true));

    System.out.println("\nVennligst tast inn fugletypen: ");
        String fugletype = input.next();
        fil.write(fugletype + ","); 

    System.out.println("Tast inn fuglens kjonn (M/H/X): ");
    char fuglekjonn = input.next().charAt(0);
    fil.write(fuglekjonn + ",");

    System.out.println("Tast inn observasjonslokasjon: ");
    String lokasjon = input.next();
    fil.write(lokasjon + ",");

    System.out.println("Tast inn dato for observasjon (Som en string på formen mai2012): ");
    String dato = input.next();
    fil.write(dato);

    fil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Åpning av fil feilet");
    }
}
```

This is where I try to make the method:

```
 void fugleType () {
System.out.println("Her kan du finne registrerte observasjoner med søk på typen fugl.");
try{
    Scanner output = new Scanner("fugler.txt");


System.out.println("Vennligst spesifiser fugletype: ");

int linjenummer = 0;

while (output.hasNext()){
    String fugletype = output.next();
    linjenummer++;
    if(fugletype.indexOf("fugler.txt")){
    System.out.println (linjenummer);
    }
}
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Fant ikke filen");
}
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

`if(fugletype.indexOf("fugler.txt"))` is not valid statement. Write it like  `if(fugletype.indexOf("fugler.txt")!= -1)`

Comment: I see that the if-statement I wrote was wrong, and that it should instead be my filename instead of "fugletype" and the Scanner-input instead of "fugler.txt". However, I then get an error that it isn't compatible. is the indexOf only for strings, and unable to run if I use a filename?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    Scanner fr = new Scanner(new FileReader("fugler.txt"));

    System.out.println("Vennligst spesifiser fugletype: ");

    int linjenummer = 0;

    while (fr.hasNextLine()){
        String fugletype = fr.nextLine();
        linjenummer++;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fugletype);

        while(s.hasNext()){ // Splits at " "

        String myString = s.next();

            if(myString.equals(stringUWant){
                System.out.println (fugletype); //entire line
            }
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Fant ikke filen");
}
```

if you want to locate a string that has spaces in it (e.g. "This is a String") I recommend using the contains method:

```
try{
    Scanner fr = new Scanner(new FileReader("fugler.txt"));

    System.out.println("Vennligst spesifiser fugletype: ");

    int linjenummer = 0;

    while (fr.hasNextLine()){
        String fugletype = fr.nextLine();
        linjenummer++;

        if(fugleType.contains(stringUwant){
            System.out.println (fugletype); //entire line
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Fant ikke filen");
}
```

Comment: Would the sysprintline I wrote print the entire line by the way?

Comment: My apologies I made a mistake in the use of FileReader, it is corrected now, and yes the println will print the whole line

Comment: Aha, thanks alot. A few questions:
To be able to choose which string it will searches for in the parenthesis (stringUwant), can I use (input) when input is the variable for in-values from Scanner from terminal? And I get an error in the line where the if(fugletype.contains) is, it says:
Oblig2.java:97: error: method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types;
                if(fugletype.contains(input)){
                            ^
  required: CharSequence
  found: Scanner
  reason: actual argument Scanner cannot be converted to CharSequence by method invocation conversion

Comment: Okay, I forgot some part of the code. But why do you use a second while-loop inside the first while-loop? And when I compile and run the program doesn't let me input anything to search for.

Comment: My second example doesn't use a second while loop, and the code I wrote doesn't take any input, since your question wasn't related to user input thus I didn't write anything that takes user input, if you need with that pedromss91@gmail.com I don't mind helping with it.